# css width of two items in a div to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a page that looks like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpCCD/), code below:

```
html:
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>

css:
.parent { width: 500px; }
.child { width: 100%; }
```

How do I get it so that together they take up 100% of the parent div width (with the text input stretching accordingly)?

To clarify: I want the button(s) in a row to be fixed width and the input to take up the remaining width of the parent so that together the width = parent width. In the case that there are no button in the row, I'd like the textinput to take up the whole width.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, use `position:absolute;left:500px;right:0` on `.child`. And you should change the structure so that `child` isn't inside `parent`. Unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: Generally, child width is `100%` i.e. 500px. What exactly you want to extend? Textfield and button? Then you've to add CSS to both the fields separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent { width: 500px; margin:auto; }
.child { width: 100%; }
```

add this to make input stretches to full width

```
.child input { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: but then they occupy two rows: http://jsfiddle.net/QpCCD/7/ I want both to take up one row where together they have a width of parent.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way to do this is to use the `display:table-x` attribute.

If you wrap the input elements in a `div` of their own like so:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="text">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then style the parent as `display:table`, the wrapper div's as `display:table-cell`, and give a width to `div.button`, like so:

```
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:table;
}
.text {
    display:table-cell;
}
.text input {
    width:100%;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
.button {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
}
```

Then you can achieve the result you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/QpCCD/9/

Comment: unfortunately I don't think this will work either. I have it set up so that with javascript a user can add or subtract rows and some rows will have multiple buttons and an input in them (all rows have either an add button, a delete button, or both), so I'd like something that is more dynamic.

Comment: Your question is specifically asking about two items. What's not dynamic about this? You can modify this in a bunch of ways, like: http://jsfiddle.net/QpCCD/25/.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @panindra's post, but it keeps both inputs on the same line.
I've added some color to the sample to be able to see the position on the screen.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: black; }
    .parent { width: 500px; background-color: white; text-align: center; }
    .child { width: 100%; position: relative; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 0px; }
    .child input { width: 49%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, this would be closer:

```
.child input { width: 248px; }
```